# Is karate variable values are altered with reference?

Tags: karate

In the below code, you can see variable defaultHeaders is copied to a new variable called myHeaders.
Now, When altering the value of myHeaders, is altering the value of defaultHeaders variable.

is this correct? am i missing something fundamental. Please explain.

I was hoping the original defaultHeaders would remain same for other scenarios to use.

Karate version: 0.9.4

```html
Feature: test one

  Background:

    * def defaultHeaders = { 'app-Id' : "defaultApp" }

  @ScenarioOne
  Scenario: scenario one
    * def myHeaders = defaultHeaders
    * print myHeaders  \\ prints {  "app-Id": "defaultApp" }
    * myHeaders["app-Id"] = 'MyNewAppId'
    * print myHeaders   \\ prints {  "app-Id": "MyNewAppId" }
    * print defaultHeaders   \\ prints {  "app-Id": "MyNewAppId" }
    * print myHeaders  \\ prints {  "app-Id": "MyNewAppId" }
    * def calltoSecond = call read('featureTwo.feature@ScenarioTwo') { customHeader: '#(myHeaders)'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please look at the `copy` keyword: https://github.com/intuit/karate#type-copy

```
* copy myHeaders = defaultHeaders
```